# In pandas Series data, how do you get the keys based on data the function returns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a working script that creates an array of each line of text in a file. This data is passed to a pandas `Series()`. The function `startswith("\n")` is used to return boolean `True` or `False` for each string, to determine if it begins with `\n` (a blank line). 
I am currently using a counter `i` and a conditional statement to iterate through and match position the `startswith()` function is returning.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
f = open('list-of-strings.txt','r')
lines = []
for line in f.xreadlines():
    lines.append(line)

s = pd.Series(lines)
i = 0
for b in s.str.startswith("\n"):
    if b == 0:
        print s[i],; i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

I've realized I am looking at this from two different approahces. One being to to directly handle each item as it is evaluated by the `startswith()` function. Since the `startswith()` function returns boolean values, it is possible to allow direct handling of data based on the values returned. Something like `for each item in startswith(), if value returned is True, index = current_index, print s[index]`.

In addition to being able to print only the strings that are evaluated as `False` by `startswith()`, how would I get the current key value from `startswith()`?

References:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_series.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_working_with_text_data.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems actually simpler than the one in the title. You're trying to get the indices for the values for which some predicate evaluated positively, not pass the index to a function.

In Pandas, the last block

```
i = 0
for b in s.str.startswith("\n"):
    if b == 0:
        print s[i],; i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

is equivalent to

```
print(s[~s.str.startswith('\n')].values)
```

Moreover, you don't need Pandas for this at all:

```
print(''.join([l for l in in open('list-of-strings.txt','r') if not l.startswith('\n')]))
```

should replace your entire block of code from the question.

Comment: That seems closer to what I am trying to achieve. This is as close as I could get to the same output as the previous code `print(s[~s.str.startswith('\n')].str.strip().to_string(index=False))`. Compare the output to `print(''.join([l for l in open('consensus-2018.txt','r') if not l.startswith('\n')]))`. I've realized what I want are the keys so I will update the question.

Comment: I have been able to get the keys with the simple `keys()` attribute and I can print the strings cleanly without all the index and spacing with the following. `keys = (s[~s.str.startswith('\n')].keys())
for key in keys:
    print s[key],` Your answer does answer the question as far as how to run an operation on the data based on the data these functions return. It's seems to be more of a Python question, but these `pandas.Series` attributes help. Thank you! https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html

Comment: You're very welcome. I'd just like to point out again that, if the question is indicative of what you're actually trying to do, then I don't think that Pandas is useful for it.

Comment: Thanks. I am just trying to get famliarized with pandas and practice coding so I can use the data analysis tools.